# show divisibility facts in detail number theory

Tags: number-theory

Show that

1. if $a | b$,   $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, then  $a\le b$
2. if $ac | bc$, then $a | b$
3. $∀ n ∈ \mathbb Z\colon  2 |(n^2-n) $
4. A Diophantine equation $$ax+by = c $$
   always has a solution whenever $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Comment: One problem per question please. Also, please show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: in first a/b means b=ak  where a and b greater then 0 and  some multiple of a is equal to b which implies that a less or equal to b.

Comment: You need to *prove* that $\,b = ak \ge a.\ \ $

Comment: it is a fact it is a multiple of a obviously it is ak greater or equal to a.

Comment: You need to *explicitly* state where you use the hypotheses since it is not true for all integers, e.g. $\ 2\mid -2,\ $ but $\ 2\le -2\ $ is false.

Answer (score 2):

1. $a\mid b\Longrightarrow b=ac\Longrightarrow|b|=|a||c|\Longrightarrow b\ge a\cdot1=a$, because $c$ can't be $0$.
2. $ac\mid bc\Longrightarrow bc=acd\Longrightarrow b=ad\Longrightarrow a\mid b$ if $c\ne0$.
3. $n^2-n=n(n-1)$, if $n$ is even, then $2\mid n\Longrightarrow2\mid n(n-1)$. If $n$ is odd, then $n-1$ is even and $2\mid n-1\Longrightarrow2\mid n(n-1)$.
4. By the [Bézout's_identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) there are $u,v$ such that $au+bv=1$. Then $a(uc)+b(vc)=c$.