# If $\,\gcd(a,b) = {\rm lcm}(a,b)\,$ then prove $a=b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that for $ a,b ∈ Z^+,\,$ if $[a,b]=(a,b),\,$ then $a=b$.

Prove if GCD if a and b is equal to LCM of a AND b then  $a=b$

Comment: It is a theorem that $ab\cot\gcd(a,b)=\lcm(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the point 1. in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732539/show-divisibility-facts-in-detail-number-theory) you know that $a\mid b\Longrightarrow a\le b$ for $a,b\in\mathbb Z^+$.

By definition $\gcd(a,b)\mid a,b$. So $\gcd(a,b)\le a,b$. Similarly $a,b\mid\text{lcm}(a,b)$ and $a,b\le\text{lcm}(a,b)$.

And because $\gcd(a,b)=\text{lcm}(a,b)$ you know that $a\le b$ and $b\le a$, therefore $a=b$.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** $\ \gcd(a,b)\mid a,b\mid {\rm lcm}(a,b)$

thus $\ \gcd(a,b)\le  a,b \le  {\rm lcm}(a,b)$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $a$ and $b$ divide $[a,b]=(a,b)$. And $(a,b)$ divides $a$ and $b$.

Conclude that $a|b$ and $b|a$...